# 'var _args = arguments' as optimization flaw

Tags: javascript, node.js, v8

I wonder if such usage of `arguments`

```
    var _args = arguments;
    arr.forEach(function (val, i) {
        arr[i] = _args[i]; 
    });
```

causes adverse effects to optimization.

Strictly it doesn't conform to any of [these optimization killers](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/wiki/Optimization-killers#3-managing-arguments) but it doesn't conform to the rule

> Never use arguments directly without .length or [i]

either. What exactly happens at low level in this case?

**JS internals are the subject of the question, and the particular implementation of array iteration is not.**

Comment: Why not just `arr = [].slice.call(arguments)`, amounts to the same thing, and still not very efficient

Comment: Well generally you don't want a reference to arguments because it sticks around. If your code is inside a function, the private member `_args` can live past the execution of the function

Comment: @adeneo The question is not about the particular implementation. Also, see https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/wiki/Optimization-killers#32-leaking-arguments

Comment: @Daniel_L That's the same link as in the question.

Comment: Is the function that uses `arguments` this way actually a bottleneck? If not, this is premature optimization, the [root of all evil](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization)

Comment: You could try ES6 [rest parameters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters) instead of `arguments`.

Comment: @AndrueAnderson That's correct, the current scenario supposes that `_args` will be used in callback but only as `_args[i]` and `_args.length` (as the paper suggests) and won't live after longer than function that owns `arguments`. @Barmar It possibly is, and improper `arguments` treatment can be n times slower, have witnessed that before.

Comment: "I wonder if x causes adverse effects to optimzation." Why not just *try it* and see what v8 does (e.g. `node --trace-opt --trace-deopt --trace-inlining foo.js`)?

Comment: @mscdex Low-level JS stuff is not my area of expertise. But thanks for the suggestion, and btw it looks like there are no deoptimizations but I'm having quite diverse benchmark results.

Comment: @estus You should provide your complete benchmarking code then.

Comment: @mscdex http://jsperf.com/foreach-arguments-vs-args It actually appears now that V8 accepts this `arguments` trick, while the rest of the browsers are unhappy with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "Never use arguments without [i] or .length" argument is less about performance, directly, and more about the black-magic of the `arguments` object.

It's impossible to tell you what's going on in *all* implementations, in *all* versions of all JS engines, because it's implementation-specific.

There are rules around its interface, but not around the implementation of the code which drives the interface.

The defined behaviour of arguments (or any alias), itself, changes depending on whether you are in strict mode or not, so performance considerations further hinge upon not only whether you're in strict or loose mode, but also the engine's implementation of both codepaths.

Creating an alias to point to `arguments` (not an array built from `arguments`) is really not going to help much at all.
It's not going to help the human maintaining it; it's not going to help the majority of engines running it.
It will still be expected to exhibit the same magical behaviour (and thus, the same performance implications) as referencing `arguments` directly (again, differing based on strict or loose operation).

This is why if you want to do anything with the magical elements (`arguments`, instances of *live* `NodeList`s, et cetera), you should put their contents in an array, or on an object. Because you pay the price of accessing/modifying elements in those magic boxes, every time you do access them.

And the only way to tell what that cost is, per engine, per engine-version, per browser, per device...
...is to test them, on all of those things, with the expectation that the only consistent truth will be that accessing/modifying elements inside of arrays will be much faster than accessing/modifying elements inside of the magical live-lists.

## Edit

Also, after having reviewed the section of Bluebird's wiki, which you linked to in comments, it becomes clearer that the black-magic is exactly what ***they*** were referring to, in the information you were given.

```
function add (a, b) {
  return a + b;
}


function unsafeAdd (a, b) {
  arguments[1] = 12;
  return a + b;
}


function safeAdd (a, b) {
  "use strict";
  arguments[1] = 41;
  return a + b;
}


add(1, 2); // 3
unsafeAdd(1, 2); // 42
safeAdd(1, 2); // 3
```

This has little to do with a speed increase ("Optimization") and more to do with protection from stupidity (or unintentional side-effects of cleverness).
But again, just looking at the behaviour differences between `safeAdd` and `unsafeAdd`, you should see exactly why the performance will ALSO change.